# how to get data using amp-state without any action

Tags: amp-html

I'm trying to get value from API using amp-state but the problem is it's like you need to do an action to get the data.

```
<amp-state id="currentTime"
  src="/documentation/examples/api/time"></amp-state>
<button on="tap:currentTime.refresh">
  Refresh
</button>
<div [text]="currentTime.time"></div>
```

in the example, above you need to click on the button refresh to get the results, is there another way to ger gata directly without doing any action?

Comment: good question. we wrestled with this awhile back. set `amp-state` with JSON data; assign the `amp-state` to an `amp-list`; parse the JSON using `amp-mustache`. i can post an answer if that makes sense.

Comment: @JayGray to understand more what I want is I show comments of an article by amp list so what I'm looking for exactly is if there are no comments I want to show 'There are no comments'. so that's why I tried with amp state because I can bring a comments count and I will hide a div base on if I have 0 comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to get data using amp-state without any action ?

As stated in the documentation:

> amp-bind expressions are not evaluated on page load, but only after an
>   user interaction has taken place. Initial amp-list content still needs
>   to be fetched from a JSON endpoint.
>
> Link:
>   https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-list/?format=websites#rendering-amp-state

This part: `[text]="currentTime.time"` is related to amp-bind. Therefore, this is not possible. Use the amp-list:

```html
<amp-state id="currentTime" src="/documentation/examples/api/time"></amp-state>

<amp-list height="100" items="." src="/documentation/examples/api/time" single-item [src]="currentTime">
  <template type="amp-mustache">
      <div [text]="currentTime.time">{{time}}</div>
   </template>
</amp-list>

<button on="tap:currentTime.refresh">Refresh</button>
```

Then it will be displayed immediately after loading the page and updated when the button is clicked.

Comment: I wonder if is it good to make pagination inside amp-list, I have already Implemented an amp-list to show posts, is it not a problem if I create another one for pagination?https://pastebin.com/RC7hpecu

Comment: I looked at your example, and I think you can do without amp-list. You can enter default values, such as hidden, disabled. In the future, the state will be updated via the local amp-state.

Comment: That's what I did in the beginning but I faced an issue when I have only 3 posts, for example, I get that I can click on the next page, but I think it's okay there is no solution for this.

Comment: If you only have three posts, you can add the hidden attribute to the next button before the first page load. But if you have a problem with this, then use amp-list freely. I often use it when I need to load data immediately after loading a page. Amp-list you can add the binding="no" attribute.